# Custom AccountManager => Refresh token (force or when expire time)

Tags: android, accountmanager

I have some trouble with an example that I found of custom `AccountManager`.
In the `getAuthToken(...)` method, there is no way to force a refresh token or/and to check if the current token is already available (like when the expiration time is over). So how do I do that properly in the code below?

```
public Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
    Log.d(TAG, "getAuthToken");
    if (!authTokenType.equals(AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS)) {
        final Bundle result = new Bundle();
        result.putBoolean(AccountManager.KEY_BOOLEAN_RESULT, true);
        result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE, "invalid authTokenType");
        return result;
    }

    final AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(context);

    String authToken = am.peekAuthToken(account, authTokenType);
    Log.d(TAG, "peekAuthToken returned - " + authToken);

    // If we get an authToken - we return it
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
        final Bundle result = new Bundle();
        result.putBoolean(AccountManager.KEY_BOOLEAN_RESULT, true);
        result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
        result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
        result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, authToken);
        return result;
    }

    return authenticate(response, account.name, false);
}
```

I think that to "force" the refresh token, I should pass some argument in the options bundle (like a boolean `"FORCE_REFRESH_TOKEN"`) and check if it's true to try to get a new token with the `refreshtoken`. But I am not sure about that way.

To check if the token is expired, the only way that I saw is to get the expired time from account user data (with `getUserData`) or from the `CredentialStore`. With that said, is it okay to save the credential in the `CredentialStore`?